# MongoDB data deleted from database

Tags: database, mongodb

I have a problem using mongodb, yesterday I was using 'test' database given by default by mongodb. I store some data and did a few queries with db.collectionName.find() and the information was there. Today I woke up to continue working and the information in my collection is no longer there. Does anyone know what could've happended? Is it because I used 'test' one of the databases given by default? I don't get it. I've been working with the database for 3 days and I did not have the problem.

Comment: Where are you running this database and is it visible to the internet and do you have authentication enabled?   What you describe is an age-old issue whereby evildoers scan IPs for an open port at 27017, try to connect, and if successful, copy out all your data and leave you a ransom note, typically in a new collection.  Do `show collections` and see if something else has popped up.

Comment: Hi, My database is running in a VM on Google cloud. I just checked the collections and nothing really popped up.

Comment: btw, I did not have any authentication enabled.

Comment: Check your logs, i.e. the `--logpath` arg.  Go near the bottom and look for `Finishing collection drop` or `table drop` in general.